# Android studio, Bluestacks Installation failed due to: 'closed'

Tags: android-studio, bluestacks

I am trying to build an android app using bluestacks (my phone died)

Android studio can see the emulator in the devices list but when i try to run my app, android studio throws this error:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: 'closed'
Retry
```

I have tried launching both android studio and bluestacks as administrator.

I have also tried opening the standalone device monitor in the SDK tools folder
This throws another error :

```
could not open Selected VM debug port(8700)
```

The error log of the monitor contains lots of errors of missing directories.

error log: https://pastebin.com/mmA83ch7

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to **Settings -> Preferences** and **Enable Android Debug Bridge, Enable android input debugging**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So someone on the bluestacks team decided that putting an adb toggle in "Preferences" and not in "advanced" was a good idea,
also literally not on any other single post has anyone said to make sure adb was toggled on.

the seting is in **Setings -> Preferences**, at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Open BlueStacks Go to **Settings** -> **Advanced** and **Enable Android Debug Bridge**, **Enable android input debugging**

Restart Bluestack and then Android Studio, this will make the connection.

happy debugging :)